# What are great grain mills that have variable coarseness such that it can be used for both brewing and making bread flour?

Tags: mill

I'm searching for a grain mill with specific qualities.  Ideally I'd like it to:

- mill grain for home brewing
- mill grain to the consistency of flour for making bread
- be able to be operated manually ( this item will double as  disaster preparedness item for accounting purposes to the boss, my wife)
- optionally may have some sort of motor attached to it for quicker milling or have a removable handle such that I can jerry rig a motor to drive the mill

Is there any mill that fits these specifications?

I realize some may think this is a duplicate, but I'm asking for one specific sub-type of a grain mill -- not grain mills fit for brewing in general as in [these](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5/best-way-to-mill-grains) [posts](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/771/can-i-use-my-country-living-grain-mill-for-homebrewing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really aren't any mills that do a good job of both crushing grain for brewing and grinding it for bread.  You have to sacrifice the performance of one or the other.  The problem is that you're talking about 2 different end products.  Grain for brewing needs to be crushed, and while you can crush it fine (I do) you don't want to completely pulverize it and turn it to flour.  Which of course is what you need a mill for bread to do!  You can use about any mill to do both jobs, but one or the other will be sub optimal.

Comment: How about half-ass for both of them :-)  Is there a grain mill where you can swap out the grinding assembly for cracking grain vs turning it to flour?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: Denny is right.  Grain mills for brewing just crack/crush the grain.  Making flour is a whole 'nother operation.